# Working with Session Variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session-variables

I am pretty clear with the defination of session variables.But I have a practical problem with session. 
I am having a view where I am using a viewData and this viewdata is assigned a value from session variable. I have this session variable placed in a controller.
In the view I have

```
ViewData["MyView"]
```

In controller

```
if(Session["MySession")!=null)
{
   ViewData["MyView"]=Session["MySession");
}
```

The above controller is common controller for each page. I mean from every other page , the control is redirected to above controller . So , following this, I have three other controllers

Controller1
Controller2
Controller3

If I click on RunReport from Page One,Control goes to Controller1 and sets a session variable

```
like Session["MySession"]=1;
```

after setting this Session, controller goes to common controller for setting ViewData[MyView] and adding value to this viewdata has different logic everytime.

Similary, when I click on Runreport from Page Two , control goes to Controller2 and Sets a session variable

```
like  Session["MySession"]=1;
```

after setting this Session, controller goes to common controller for setting ViewData[MyView] and adding value to this viewdata has different logic everytime. By this I mean to say ViewData will have different values everytime.

Similary, when I click from Page Three, control behaves and everthing in same manner.

Everything is working for now. But My problem is that I am using Same session Variable in each different controller. Suppose User1 has opened  page1 and he clicks on runreport page , ofcourse this session variable will have now a value and after this control will go to Common controller and sets a value in view data. At the same time if another uses opens page2 and he clicks on runreport , then on its click again this process will be followed or the previous session will already have a value even If I click on runreport or not. Actually I am totally confused. Please Help Me. give some technically points of understanding sessions deeply at practical level and please clear my point. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Session` is per-user collection even if it looks like static in `HttpContext.Current.Session`. Two different users will get different `Session` object and every new user will get its own empty `Session` object.

Comment: Okay , This means for every new user there will be a new session variable created. Now suppose I am first user and this user opens page1 and then click on runreport page which will redirect to controller1 there a session is created and control will go to commonController and sets ViewData. Now, the session is still on the memory. Then , I opened page2 and click runreprt button and similarly for that a new Session veriable Will be created or the first session variable will be overrided? Or suppose If i just opens  page2 and do not click on runreport button then the session will still in the mem

Comment: continued from last comment---   Memory? Actually what will be the effect on this session variable . Please help me ASAP. I will be thankful to you

Comment: I can't see your actual problem. You have a common persitence area for all your pages with the Session, every time you access with a key name you change the value of this peristence unit variable and that for a user and for a time period after what the Session is cleared.

Answer (score 0):

There are great tutorials out there about the basics of the MVC framework.

http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4